# C++ merge 2 wchar_t*

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an interesting problem and I'm not sure why.

```
inline void mergeWChar(wchar_t*& dest, const wchar_t* source) {
    if (dest == nullptr) {
        dest = const_cast<wchar_t*>(source);
        return;
    }
    int size = wcslen(dest);
    wcscat_s(dest, size, source);
}
inline void test() {
    wchar_t* msg = nullptr;
    wchar_t* t = L"BLA.BLA.BLA";
    mergeWChar(msg, L"Ts is jut a phrase in order to test my function");
    mergeWChar(msg, t);
}
```

I'm trying to make a function that will merge tougher 2 wchar_t* using the wcscat_s function but from some reason is not working and I'm receiving this error message.

> Exception thrown at 0x5D8C3A18 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0082DD60.

Also, I've checked these 2 questions already and is not really helped me.

[wcscat_s problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123157/wcscat-s-problem)

[wcscat_s function - buffer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783456/wcscat-s-function-buffer-error)

**WHAT I CAN'T DO**

I'm working with some legacy code and I can **NOT** use some things like:

1. wstring
2. to_wstring
3. wchar_t var[size] <- that's not going to work.

Comment: `wchar_t* t = L"BLA.BLA.BLA";` doesn't compile on my side. "cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [12]' to 'wchar_t *'"

Comment: This is bad, `dest = const_cast<wchar_t*>(source);`. You promised you wouldn't modify `source`, but then you gave the caller a non-const pointer to it. Who or what is supposed to allocate the memory for the concatenated output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
mergeWChar(msg, t);
```

`msg` points to the string literal `L"Ts is jut a phrase in order to test my function"`. You cannot modify a string literal.

You want this:

```
inline void mergeWChar(wchar_t*& dest, const wchar_t* source) {
  if (dest == nullptr) {
    dest = const_cast<wchar_t*>(source);
    return;
  }

  wchar_t *newdest = (wchar_t*)malloc((wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1) * sizeof *newdest);
  wcscpy(newdest, dest);      // the *_s functions are useless here
  wcscat(newdest, source);    // as you know that newdest point to
                              // a long enough buffer
  dest = newdest;
}
```

Disclaimer: no error checking is done here for brevity.

The origin of the problem is the poor design of the `mergeWChar` function and the questionable use of `const_cast<wchar_t*>` which basically allows you to assign a pointer to a constant string to a normal pointer, which then allows you to modify that constant memory which eventually fails.

However there is a problem with this design: you cannot free the allocated memory because the `dest` pointer is not necessarily a pointer that has been obained via `malloc`. Therefore following design is better IMO:

```
inline void mergeWChar(wchar_t*& dest, const wchar_t* source) {
  int size = (dest ? wcslen(dest) : 0) + wcslen(source) + 1;
  wchar_t *newdest = (wchar_t*)malloc(size * sizeof *newdest);
  if (dest)
    wcscpy(newdest, dest);
  else
    newdest[0] = 0;
  wcscat(newdest, source);
  dest = newdest;
}
```

That way there is no ugly cast and no risc of a non const pointer pointing to constant memory and you can be sure that the pointer modified by `mergeWChar` can be freed no matter what. The cost is that you need more memory.

Example of usage:

```
...
wchar_t* msg = nullptr;
wchar_t* t = L"BLA.BLA.BLA";
mergeWChar(msg, L"Ts is jut a phrase in order to test my function");
mergeWChar(msg, t);
...
free(msg);
...
```

Comment: Your idea is good and everything it's working properly with one exception. You are using **malloc** over there, you are not supposed to delete also that or the current **dest**? Because so far I can see there is a memory leak, no?

Comment: @Mircea yes, yof course you need to take care of that, and therefore you should use the second version anyway. I edited the question.